# Easy exponentiation method

Tags: recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

Is there a simple way of solving, say, $x^{3/2}$?

For example, one way of solving $16^{3/2}$ is to calculate the square root of $16^3$, but I was wondering if there is a simpler mental trick for doing this that generalizes to all possible exponentiation.

Comment: You mean by hand? You can have good approximation by either Taylor expansion or Newton's method...if you have enough time.

Comment: Probably the fastest *general* method for doing this mentally is applying a trick to compute $\sqrt{x}$ and multiplying by $x$. In your example, one can simply use $16^{3/2} = (2^4)^{3/2} = 2^{4 \cdot 3/2} = 2^6 = 64$, and this applies just as well to integers that are actually a suitable power of an integer already. Like Troy says, if you're near a number $x_0$ for which you already know the appropriate power, say, if you're trying to compute $16.1^{3/2}$, you can get a good approximation from the Taylor series for $x^{3/2}$ based at $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you could see that $16=4^2$ then you could do this

$$\left(4^2\right)^{3/2}=4^3$$

If you can see such a number that would be the fastest method, another method would be the one rae306 mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Following Troy Woo and Travis comments, let us make it more general : you want to know $x$ such that $$x^a=b$$ and you know already a solution for a given $a$ and a value close to $b$.

Newton method is quite simple since, starting at your known estimate $x_0$, the first iterate will be $$x_1=x_0-\frac{x_0^{1-a} \left(x_0^a-b\right)}{a}$$

Let us apply it to $a=\frac{3}{2}$, $b=10$ and $x_0=4$. This gives $$x_1=\frac{14}{3} \simeq 4.66667$$ while the exact solution is $4.64159$

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is to apply an exponential rule:

$$x^{\frac{3}{2}}=x\cdot\sqrt{x}$$

Example:

$$16^{\frac{3}{2}}=16\cdot\sqrt{16}=16\cdot4=64$$